# Set Postcode/ZIP From Google Auto Complete

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am attempting code that when I enter an address in to a text box it shows the address then shortens to only postcode - much like gif below..

Came across this link but does not seem to work - but on the right lines
https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/647425/Set-Postal-Code-in-TextBox-from-Google-Place-Autocomplete-result-selection-using-JavaScript/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />




  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&amp;libraries=places"></script>

<script>
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function initialize() 
    {
     var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_search');
     var options = 
     {
         componentRestrictions: {country: 'gb'}
     };
     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

      var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_search');
      //var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      // place variable will have all the information you are looking for.
      $('#lat').val(place.geometry['location'].lat());
      $('#long').val(place.geometry['location'].lng());
    });
  }
</script>


  <title>Google Places Autocomplete InputBox Example Without Showing Map - Tutsmake.com</title>
 <style>
    .container{
    padding: 10%;
    text-align: center;
   } 
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><h2>Google Places Autocomplete InputBox Example Without Showing Map</h2></div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="autocomplete_search" name="autocomplete_search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="lat">
                    <input type="hidden" name="long">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When entering an address such Nevile Road, it does not show postcode (and that's all I want). Is there a way to get the postcode from the autocomplete address.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXO8y.gif]

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to filter Place Autocomplete predictions on postcodes only. Take a look at [this open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067) in Google's Issue Tracker.

But you *can* choose to display only the postcode for a selected place in the search box, instead of the full address. In your example, you could change the `place_changed` listener as follows:

```
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      $('#lat').val(place.geometry['location'].lat());
      $('#long').val(place.geometry['location'].lng());

      let postcode;
      for (let i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        let types = place.address_components[i].types;
        for (let type of types) {
          if (type === "postal_code") {
            postcode = place.address_components[i].long_name;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!postcode) {
        postcode = place.formatted_address;
      }
      $('#autocomplete_search').val(postcode);
    });
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4rnmazw/) (add your API key to run it).

With the above code implementation, now if you type in "Nevile Road" into the text field, and select the first place prediction, `Nevile Road, Salford, UK`, you'll get its `postal_code_prefix` as the only value, i.e. `M7`.

Likewise, if you start typing a full postcode, e.g. "M7 3PP", you'll get a `Nevile Road, Salford M7 3PP, UK` place suggestion, and selecting it will give you `M7 3PP`.

However, note that this won't always work as there are many addresses that don't have a single, specific postcode. E.g. "London, UK" won't return any postcode at all (as it obviously can't).

Hope this helps!